# HSV color detection with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, hsv

The "red" color-detection is not working yet. The following code is supposed to detect a red bar from an input-image and return a mask-image showing a white bar at the corresponding location.

The corresponding HSV-values of the "red" bar in the inputRGBimage are : H = 177, S = 252, V = 244

```
    cv::Mat findColor(cv::Mat inputRGBimage) {

    cv::Mat imageHSV(inputRGBimage.rows, inputRGBimage.cols, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat imgThreshold(inputRGBimage.rows, inputRGBimage.cols, CV_8UC1);

    // convert input-image to HSV-image
    cvtColor(inputRGBimage, imageHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    // for red: (H < 14)
    // cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(0, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(14, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);
    // or (H > 165) (...closing HSV-circle)
    cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(165, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);

    return imgThreshold;
}
```

The two images below show the inputRGBimage (top) and the returned imgThreshold (bottom). As you can see, the mask is not showing the white bar at the expected color "red" but shows it for some unknown reason at the "blue" bar. Why ????

[image: wrong mask 01]

The following change of the cv::inRange line of code (i.e. H > 120) and its result again illustrates that the color detection is not actually acting as expected :

```
    // or (H > 120) (...closing HSV-circle)
    cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(120, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);
```

[image: wrong mask 02]

As a third example: (H > 100):

```
    // or (H > 100) (...closing HSV-circle)
    cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(100, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold);
```

[image: wrong mask 03]

Why the unexpected order of colors in my 3 code-examples (decreasing the H-value from 165 to 100) showing mask orders of "blue->violet->red->orange" instead of the actually expected HSV-wheel rough order of "red->violet->blue->green->yellow->orange" ?????

[image: HSV table]

HSV in OpenCV has ranges: 
0 <= H <= 180,
0 <= S <= 255,
0 <= V <= 255, (not quite like in the illustrating graphic above - but the order of colors should be the same for OpenCV HSV-colors - or not ???)

Comment: 2 things: 1st hue is splitted in 2 regions: 0 to x and x to 180 so you need two inRange or you have to "shift" your hue. 2nd: maybe increase saturation and value range to 0..255 or n..255

Comment: your testresults are strange though. will test tomorrow

Comment: Your input is called `inputRGBimage` but you convert it to HSV using the flag `cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV`. So, which channel order are you using, RGB or BGR? If you use the former, it would explain why the blue regions are detected.

Comment: @nils: Thank you for the hint ! I did indeed overlooked the RGB vs. BGR detail in my code ! Replacing cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV by cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV, it all works !!

Comment: By the way, using SWIFT, the image originates from an UIImage and therefore (with nils' hint) now undergoes the following conversions: UIImage->RGBA2RGB->RGB->HSV....  The two methods used for the OpenCV-wrapper are:     for (id image in imageArray) {
        if ([image isKindOfClass: [UIImage class]]) {
            cv::Mat matImage = [image CVMat3];
            matImages.push_back(matImage);
        }
    } and     - (cv::Mat)CVMat3
{
    cv::Mat result = [self CVMat];
    cv::cvtColor(result , result , CV_RGBA2RGB);
    return result;
}

Comment: @skuenstler Could you integrate the code snippet from you comment into your question. It's rather unreadable in its current form (at least for me).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the image uses the channel order B, G, R. Also, for the color red you need check two ranges of values, one around `H=0` and the other around `H=180`. You could try this function:

```
cv::Mat findColor(const cv::Mat & inputBGRimage, int rng=15)
{
    // Make sure that your input image uses the channel order B, G, R (check not implemented).
    cv::Mat input = inputBGRimage.clone();
    cv::Mat imageHSV;//(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat imgThreshold, imgThreshold0, imgThreshold1;//(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC1);
    assert( ! input.empty() );

    // convert input-image to HSV-image
    cv::cvtColor( input, imageHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV );

    // In the HSV-color space the color 'red' is located around the H-value 0 and also around the
    // H-value 180. That is why you need to threshold your image twice and the combine the results.
    cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(      0, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(rng, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold0);

    if ( rng > 0 )
    {
        cv::inRange(imageHSV, cv::Scalar(180-rng, 53, 185, 0), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255, 0), imgThreshold1);
        cv::bitwise_or( imgThreshold0, imgThreshold1, imgThreshold );
    }
    else
    {
        imgThreshold = imgThreshold0;
    }

    return imgThreshold;
}
```

Good luck! :)